# Draw full line using itextsharp

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, itext, wkhtmltopdf

For conversion from HTML to PDF I used `wkhtmltopdf`because of css support.. but I want to draw full line width of pdf page..I used `HR` and `DIV` for that but it left some margin before and after it may b because of I passed argument as  `args+= "--margin-top 10mm --margin-bottom 10mm --margin-right 3mm --margin-left 3mm ";`..so I am using ITextsharp for this..but it doesn't draw line
I tried below code:

```
        PdfContentByte cb;
        // DO PAGE NUMBER
        byte[] bytes1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\temp\test_QA.pdf");
        var FontColour = new BaseColor(97, 123, 149);
        iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontNormal = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, FontColour);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes1);
            var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            writer.PageEvent = new iTextEvents();
            //Open the document for writing                                                
            doc.Open();
            cb = writer.DirectContent;
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
            {
                cb.MoveTo(0, doc.PageSize.Height - 55);
                cb.LineTo(doc.PageSize.Width, doc.PageSize.Height - 55);
                cb.SetColorStroke(FontColour);
                cb.Stroke();

                //Move the pointer and draw line to separate footer section from rest of page
                cb.MoveTo(0, doc.PageSize.GetBottom(150));
                cb.LineTo(doc.PageSize.Width, doc.PageSize.GetBottom(55));
                cb.SetColorStroke(FontColour);
                cb.Stroke();
            }
            bytes1 = stream.ToArray();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\download.pdf", bytes1);
            //doc.Close();
        }
```

any idea what is missing here?

Comment: Yikes, you use both a `Document`/`PdfWriter` couple (creating a new PDF) and a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` couple (manipulating an existing PDF) *writing to the same stream*! You should not expect that to produce anything but garbage. Instead only use a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` couple and change its `OverContent`.

Comment: ok I remove both thing and did `doc.Open();
                    cb = writer.DirectContent;


                    cb.MoveTo(0, doc.PageSize.Height - 55);
                    cb.LineTo(doc.PageSize.Width, doc.PageSize.Height - 55);
                    cb.SetColorStroke(FontColour);
                    cb.Stroke();`.. still it doesn't draw a line @mkl

Comment: I recommended using *only a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` couple and change its `OverContent`.* The code in your comment shows that you did the opposite. So what do you expect?

Comment: I want to draw a line above footer which I already bind with `wkhtmltopdf`.. @mkl

Comment: That been said your code is wrong in another way: You first create a path (`cb.MoveTo`, `cb.LineTo`), then you set the color (`cb.SetColorStroke`), then you try to use the path (`cb.Stroke`). This creates invalid content according to the PDF specification: There shall not be other instructions between the creation and the use of a path.

Comment: can you write a snippet for that..@mkl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use both a `Document`/`PdfWriter` couple (creating a new PDF) and a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` couple (manipulating an existing PDF) *writing to the same stream*! You should not expect that to produce anything but garbage. Instead only use a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` couple and change its `OverContent`.

Furthermore, your code is wrong in another way: You first create a path (`cb.MoveTo`, `cb.LineTo`), then you set the color (`cb.SetColorStroke`), then you try to use the path (`cb.Stroke`). This creates invalid content according to the PDF specification: There shall not be other instructions between the creation and the use of a path.

Thus, use something like this (untested, merely changed your code in editor here):

```
var FontColour = new BaseColor(97, 123, 149);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"E:\temp\test_QA.pdf"))
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
    {
        Rectangle rect = reader.GetPageSize(1);
        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
        cb.SetColorStroke(FontColour);
        cb.MoveTo(0, rect.Height - 55);
        cb.LineTo(rect.Width, rect.Height - 55);
        cb.MoveTo(0, rect.GetBottom(150));
        cb.LineTo(rect.Width, rect.GetBottom(55));
        cb.Stroke();
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\download.pdf", stream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Just last question..table in pdf is overridden on header line..do I need to set any css?

Comment: @Dhara Well, you currently use `--margin-top 10mm` in your wkhtmltopdf call. That is not much. Thus, either use a larger `--margin-top` argument or change `rect.Height - 55` to subtract less from `rect.Height`.

Comment: Thank you..it works.. `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("XSWQAZ", baseFontNormal), 0f, 0f, 0);` add thing in footer.. I need to add in header..is there anything missin?

Comment: If you know how to add text in the footer area but now want to add text in the header area, you should change the coordinates in the footer area to coordinates in the header area.